# Audio devices not listed for playback

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Newbie and I messed something up. I originally had sound but now I do not.

When I use `aplay -l` I get this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

But if I use `lspci -v` I can see my onboard audio:

> 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller
>   (rev 09)  Subsystem: Dell Device 0665     Flags: bus master, fast devsel,
>   latency 0, IRQ 66     Memory at f741c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable)
>   [size=16K]    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
>     Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
>     Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
>     Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
>
> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High
>   Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)  Subsystem: Dell Device 0665
>     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 65  Memory at
>   f7418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]    Capabilities: [50]
>   Power Management version 3    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1
>   Maskable- 64bit+  Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

How do I get my audio devices to show up as a playback option? I've tried everything in the sound troubleshooting area with no luck.